# What is the best practices to track action id in controller for saved form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Wasnt sure how to word the question, but this is the scenario:

the view is a data entry form eg http://127.0.0.1/User/AddEdit/

so edit the user I have an ID: http://127.0.0.1/User/AddEdit/7838fd9c-425c-4c98-b798-771bba10d9c1

This ID gets the data to populate the form values in a ViewModel, which populates the form

I am using jquery/ajax to save the form, which returns a Json result, indicating ok/error etc

In the View, I get the ID and use this in a hidden field which is set via jquery when the page loads and when the form is saved via ajax.

This seems a bit clunky, how do others do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion best solution is to create a partial view with all the fields and use it on add and edit view which are separate actions in controller. after you create user you can redirect to action edit. if you must / like use ajax you can reload div with form (change from user/add to user/edit/1). i might be wrong but i never see a code or example with one action in controller for add and edit.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I could just redirect the user back to the page with the ID, which is whjat I do on other pages, it just seems nicer to save without the additinal request and database hit. The AddEdit View basically gets the data and populates the form, then the Save View just saves the form and returns Json. which could in theory be use in any page to save data.